# Laplace transform of $x^a$

Tags: laplace-transform

How to prove that the Laplace transform of $x^a$ is: 
$$\mathcal{L}\{x^a\}(s)=\frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{ s^{a+1}}$$
Also how to prove that the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{ s^{a+1}}$ is $x^a$? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: By inverse function do you mean the inverse Laplace transform?

Comment: yes, inverse Laplace transform function; thanks for help me edit it in Latex : )

Comment: The standard way of proving that the inverse Laplace transform of $X$ is $Y$ is to prove that the Laplace transform of $Y$ is $X$. (Most authors just say "it's complicated" and brush it under the furniture when asked how to calculate inverse Laplace transforms.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, the Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}(x^a)$ of the function $x\mapsto x^a$ is given by
$$
\mathcal{L}(x^a)(s) = \int_0^\infty \exp(-sx)x^a\mathrm{d}x.
$$

The Gamma function is defind by a similar integral, namely
$$
\Gamma(s)=\int_0^\infty \exp(-x)x^{s-1}\mathrm{d}x.
$$

The Laplace transform of $x^a$ can thus be computed by the variable transformation $x\mapsto x/s$.

Comment: then for the inverse function, I was wondering how to prove integral of (1/2pi*i)e^ptL(p) = x^a

Comment: How can one make a substitution of a complex variable with a real variable? What happens to the bounds of integration?

Answer (score 6):

You should use the definition of Laplace transform and of the Gamma function:
$$\mathcal{L}\{f(x)\}(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}f(x)dx,\hspace{10pt} \Gamma(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{\alpha-1}dt$$
Just substitute $f(x)=x^a$ and change the variable $sx\mapsto t$.

Comment: How can one make a substitution of a complex variable with a real variable? What happens to the bounds of integration?

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
\mathcal L\left\{ x^{a}\right\}&=\int\limits_0^\infty x^{a}e^{-{s}x}\text dx
\\\text{let } x=\frac u{s}\qquad\quad\text dx=\frac{\text du}{s}&
\\x=0\rightarrow u=0\qquad x=\infty\rightarrow u=\infty&\\
\\&=\int\limits_0^\infty \left(\frac u{s}\right)^{a}e^{-{s}\frac u{s}}\frac{\text du}{s}
\\&=\frac{1}{{s}^{{a}+1}}\int\limits_0^\infty u^{a}e^{-u} {\text du}\\
\\&=\frac{\Gamma({a}+1)}{{s}^{{a}+1}}&\qquad a\in\mathbb C\big|\Re(a)\geq-1\\
\\&\color{grey}{=\frac{{a}!}{{s}^{{a}+1}},}&\qquad \color{grey}{{a}\in\mathbb Z\geq0}
\end{align*}

---

\begin{align*}
\mathcal L\left\{ x^{a}\right\}=\frac{\Gamma({a}+1)}{{s}^{{a}+1}}\\
% \mathcal L^{-1}\Big\{\mathcal L\left\{ x^{a}\right\}\Big\}=\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\frac{\Gamma({a}+1)}{{s}^{{a}+1}}\right\}\\
x^{a}=\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\frac{\Gamma({a}+1)}{{s}^{{a}+1}}\right\}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Isn't a greater than -1?

Comment: How can one make a substitution of a complex variable with a real variable? What happens to the bounds of integration?

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of laplace transform 
ie. in your case ,
$$F(s) = \int_0^\infty x^a e^{-sx} dx$$